# Convert single object into array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object that looks like:

```
var data = {first: '12/1/2019', second: '12/15/2019'}
```

I am trying to get into an array of objects using its keys and values like so:

```
var array = [ 
  {phase: 'first', date: '12/1/2019'}, 
  {phase: 'second', date: '12/15/2019'}
]
```

I have tried various things, but the closest I have gotten is using something like:

```
var array = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => ({key,value}));
```

This gives me an array of objects like:

```
[ 
 {key: 'first', value: '12/1/2019'},
 {key: 'second', value: '12/15/2019'}
]
```

I'm close! but i can't figure out how to change key and value to be phase and date. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually just rename your key and value parameter names:

```
var array = Object.entries(data).map(([phrase, date]) => ({phrase,date}));
```

Comment: Thanks! I had something like this, but I think I only changed it one place as opposed to both.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding labels in object.

```js
var data = {
  first: '12/1/2019',
  second: '12/15/2019'
}

var array = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => ({
  phase: key,
  date: value
}))

console.log(array)
```

Comment: I wonder why I don't see any difference between your answer and brk's answer below.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt he don't have `;` at end and brk have `;`

Comment: @Krishna Prashatt That was a joke nvm

Comment: @Krishna Prashatt That makes no difference both are correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190413/discussion-between-krishna-prashatt-and-maheer-ali).

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there try by adding the key to return object

```js
var data = {
  first: '12/1/2019',
  second: '12/15/2019'
}
var array = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => ({
  phase: key,
  date: value
}));
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` on `Object.keys()`

```js
var data = {first: '12/1/2019', second: '12/15/2019'}

let arr = Object.keys(data).map(x => ({phase:x,date:data[x]}))
console.log(arr)
```

You can also use `Object.entries()` and `map()` but give different names to the parameters destructed

```js
var data = {first: '12/1/2019', second: '12/15/2019'}
let arr = Object.entries(data).map(([phase,date]) =>({phase,date}))
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

First extract the `key` (phase) and `value` (date) from the data object by **[`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)** then use **[`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** to accumulate and form the new object into an array.

```js
const data = {first: '12/1/2019', second: '12/15/2019'}
const arr = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [phase, date]) => acc.concat({phase, date}), []);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution using [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterates over all non-Symbol, enumerable properties of an object.

```js
const data = { first: '12/1/2019', second: '12/15/2019' };
const dataset = [];

for (const key in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    const element = data[key];

    dataset.push({
      phase: key,
      date: element
    });
  }
}

console.log(dataset);
```